# How to filter the view2 fields and show by clicking on view1 node

Tags: views

I have view1 and view2,  when I click on the node link of view1 say

ex:  **id [mc]** it should get view2 and display corresponding  information like strain , projects etc based on the **id[mc]**.

So far to get the view2 while clicking on view1 node, I have performed following,

- In view1 I have rewritten the tittle[node] output to link and specified the path of view2.
- Given contextual filter to filter and to get the related field value of view2.

Problem is **when I click on particular node of view1 it gives the view2 but it is not filtering based on the  node we have clicked**.

So can you please tell me how to filter and get the field values of view2.

[image]

Comment: what are you using as your contextual filter?

Comment: @NoSssweat: Thanks for replying me.... i am using entity reference field of view2 [ its referring the nid of view1]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your view's Advanced settings

Comment: @NoSssweat: yea sure i will .....

Comment: @NoSssweat:  first screen is view2 stetting and second one is view1 i,e i am rewritting the output to link and specifying the path of view2

Comment: so let me get this straight. So you have view1 which shows up in /node/1. View1 has a link to /node/2. Node2 has a view2 which shows fields from Node2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31130/discussion-between-neethu-and-no-sssweat).

Comment: @NoSssweat are you there?

Comment: @NoSssweat: hey wassup? you there?

Comment: yea, lets chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35445/neethu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1)**

I added a Entity Reference field called 111 to my Content Type

[image]

**Step 2)**

In view1 in **RELATIONSHIPS** click Add

- in search type `ref`
- select **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity**

[image]

**Step 3)**

In **FIELDS** click add, select **File Usage: Entity ID**.

- Under Relationship, select your entity reference
- check mark exclude from display.
- Thousand Marker, select none

[image]

**Step 4)**

**Move** your **title** field **below** the File Usage: Entity ID field.

[image]

**Step 5)**

Click on your Title field.

- Uncheck link this title to the original piece of content
- Under Rewrite results, checkmark output this field as a link
- link path: `/view2/[id]`

[image]

**Save view1**

**Open View 2**

**Step 1)**

**Add a Contextual Filter** of **File Usage: Entity ID** (Do the same as picture below)

[image]

**Step 2)**

In **RELATIONSHIPS** click Add

- in search type `ref`
- select **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity**

[image]

**Step 3)**

Change the page path settings to `/view2/%`

[image]

### **DONE :)**